# Pyside / PyQt: How to send information between classes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

I'm trying to make a program that allows the user to manually select a file or just drag and drop a file into the `MainWindow`.

The file browser works and MainWindow accepts drops but I can't figure out how to:

1. Get `filePath` out of class `myMainWindow` and into class `Ui_MainWindow`
2. Change `pushButton`'s text to 'File Selected' when a file has been dropped.

It seems that I need to use emit()/signal() to send information between the two classes but I can't figure out how to connect them.

Full code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class myMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.filePath = ''

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                self.filePath = (str(url.toLocalFile()))
                # What else do I do here?
        else:
            event.ignore()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def selectFile(self):
        self.filePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        self.pushButton.setText('File Selected')
        print(self.filePath)

    def myChanges(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.selectFile)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 180, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.myChanges()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Browse", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = myMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You could explain the first point better.

Comment: When I run this code, it pops up a huge window with a button that is labeled "Browse". When I hit that button, it pops up a QFileDIalog window and once I select a file, the text on the button changes to "File Selected". So at least one of the things you want to happen happens.

Comment: I ask you about the first point

Comment: In `dropEvent`, I'm setting `self.filePath` to the location of the file dropped into `MainWindow`. (If you type in 'print(self.filePath)' on the line with the comment you'll see the file path outputted as a string)  My question is how can I transfer the string inside `self.filePath` on line 27 into `class Ui_MainWindow`?

Comment: Signals and slots are the correct method to communicate between Qt objects, but why do you require the `Ui_MainWindow` class? All of its functionality can be merged into `myMainWindow`. Then you should be able to handle everything from within `dropEvent`

Answer (score 3):

The only way to "send information between classes" (or have them communicate) in any Object Oriented language is through messages (e.g. python's methods). Pyside's/Qt's signals are used when you are dealing with multiple threads and you need something to be executed in the main thread (where the visual things happen). Pyside's/Qt's signals are also used when you want to connect an action (e.g. clicking a button to an image being showed).

In your example, I think the best would be to have the classes known each other (have references to each other) and send messages when needed. For example, when you call setupUI you pass mainWindow as an argument. Inside that method, you could have something like

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    self._mainWindow = MainWindow
    mainWindow.setUi(self)
```

The setUi method would save that class as an attribute. Then on the DropEvent you can just send the path to the UI as an argument of another message.